# Will `resize` have any risk to reduce the vector capacity?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management, std

In C++, the method `resize` (of `std::vector`), changes the size of the vector (and construct / destroys object if necessary), `reserve` allows to eventually increase the capacity of a vector. `shrink_to_fit` will reduce the capacity of the vector to match its size. When increasing the vector size (either through `resize`, `push_back` or `insert`), the capacity will be increased if needed (it doubles every time it needs to increase if I am not mistaken).

Do the standards ensure that a vector will never reduce its capacity, unless the function `shrink_to_fit` is called? Or is it possible that a vector capacity will vary depending upon what the compiler think being wise to do?

Comment: I think the docs did answer the question though with `Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size`. I only read the [cplusplus docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) before asking which don't make such mention. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the vector's capacity will not be reduced by `reserve` or `resize`.

[`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

> If `new_cap` is [not greater than `capacity`] ... no iterators or references are invalidated.

[`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize#Notes)

> Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators, rather than only the ones that would be invalidated by the equivalent sequence of pop_back() calls.

[Relevant part of the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#capacity)

Comment: Thank you. I think cppreference.com tend to be better than cplusplus.com and should always look at their instead. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes exactly :)

Comment: @Remi.b Yeah, cppreference tends to be at least slightly better. I've actually blacklisted cplusplus.com so that it doesn't appear in my google searches...